# Operator does not exist: jsonb = integer

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, jsonb, ahoy

I am getting the following postgres error:

"operator does not exist: jsonb = integer"

[image: operator does not exist: jsonb = integer]

I have my application hosted on Heroku and am using a Postgres 9.4 DB. Below is what my accounts controller looks like with the ahoy_matey analytics gem.

**Accounts Controller**

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    if current_user.business_id
      @business = Business.find(current_user.business_id)
      # analytics
      @monthly_business_views = ahoy_event_sum("Page Viewed", @business.id)
      @monthly_get_websites = ahoy_event_sum("Visited Website", @business.id)
      @monthly_get_directions = ahoy_event_sum("Directions Viewed", @business.id)
      @monthly_get_fb_shares = ahoy_event_sum("Shared via Facebook", @business.id)
      @monthly_get_tweets = ahoy_event_sum("Tweeted via Twitter", @business.id)
      @reviews = Review.where(:business_id => @business).all
    end
  end

  ...

  def ahoy_event_sum(event, business_id)
    Ahoy::Event.where(name:event, properties: business_id).count
  end

end
```

**Ahoy Events Model**

```
module Ahoy
  class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "ahoy_events"

    belongs_to :visit
    belongs_to :user

    serialize :properties, JSON
  end
end
```

I have intermediate skills and apologize if this question has a simple fix, please provide any details on how I would solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: I assume, "ahoy_events"."properties" column is `jsonb` and you are trying to compare it with  `integer` value `1`. btw -  are you using `json` OR `jsonb` ? https://github.com/ankane/ahoy#postgresql-94--jsonb

Comment: @Dmitry I am using `jsonb`

Comment: so `ahoy` data model should contain  `jsonb`

Comment: @Dmitry is that a solution or a question... I'm getting confused :(

Answer (score 0):

Update the query to filter by the `properties` column directly, instead of using the `serialize` method:

```rb
Ahoy::Event.where(name: event, properties: { business_id: business_id }).count
```

The `serialize` method is not necessary because the `properties` column is already a JSONB column, which is a native serialization type in PostgreSQL:

```rb
# serialize :properties, JSON
```